# Warning cplexlink1261 using Cplex for Matlab: unsupported Matlab verions?

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, cplex

I made a code that solve a Mixed Integer Linear Problem (MILP). In order to be as fast as possible, my code is using Cplex functions to solve the MILP, `cplexmilp` and `cplexoptimset`.
The only thing I set on `cplexoptimset` is:

```
 options =cplexoptimset ('Display','off');
```

And than I run:

```
x = cplexmilp(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,options)
```

When I run the code, I receive the warning:

```
Warning: The function 'cplexlink1261' returned an mxArray with non-temporary scope
In cplexoptimset/secCplexOptions
In cplexoptimset /setCplexOptions
In cplexoptimset
In cplexoptimset
In myfunction
```

Nevertheless, after this warning, the code keep running, and it provides me results that seems reasonable.

I surfed the internet looking for an answer, and I found that the reason may be that my Matlab version, 2015b, is not supported for cplex.

Therefore, my question is: can I still trust the results I get from the function? My solution is a binary vector of thousands of variables, so I cannot actually check. Nevertheless, I noticed that other results derived from the code are similar to results I recorded before using the `cplexmilp`function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I surfed the internet looking for an answer, and I found that the reason may be that my Matlab version, 2015b, is not supported for cplex.

Yes, that is correct; your version of MATLAB is not supported.  See the [Detailed system requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100) for your version of CPLEX (presumably 12.6.1).

> Therefore, my question is: can I still trust the results I get from the function?

It's not supported, so it's not tested.  Use it at your own risk.  If you want to be sure of your results, then use a supported version of MATLAB.  I know that is not a very satisfying answer, but it is probably the best you'll get.

It looks like it may be possible to disable the warning (as shown [here](https://github.com/johanlofberg/YALMIP/issues/341)), but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: I understand. I will look for a supported Matlab version I guess. Thank you a lot.